# A divisible free abelian group must be trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Prove that a divisible free abelian group must be trivial.

Here is my attempt:

Assume $G$ is a divisible free abelian group non-trivial. Since $G$ is free it has a basis, say $\{x_1,...,x_n\} \subset G$, so every element $g \in G$, $g=a_1x_1+....+a_2x_2$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $i=1,2,...,n.$ Moreover, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ being fixed, there are $h_1,...,h_n \in G$ such that $x_i=nh_i$ for all $i=1,2,3...,n$. I do not know how to get fourther from this information.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: First, there is no reason to assume $G$ is free abelian **of finite rank**. You shouldn’t. I assume that “$a_2x_2$” is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is free abelian of nonzero rank; let $X$ be a basis for $G$, and let $x\in X$. Then there exists $g\in G$ such that $2g=x$; in particular, there exist pairwise distinct $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in X$ and integers $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ such that $g=a_1x_1+\cdots +a_nx_n$. Without loss of generality, we may take $x_1 = x$ (by adding it with $a_1=0$ if necessary).

Then $x_1 = x = 2g = 2(a_1x_1+\cdots + a_nx_n)$, hence
$$0 = (2a_1-1)x_1+2a_2x_2+\cdots+2a_nx_n.$$
Why is that a problem in a free abelian group, with $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ pairwise distinct elements of a basis?

Comment: because we have $a_i \neq 0$ for some i?!

Comment: @Ahmed. No, we don't know if the $a_i$ are nonzero (we never assumed that was the case). But there is one coefficient that we can *guarantee* is nonzero in that last expression. Which one? And why, explicitly, is that a problem?