# Showing that the additive group on the dyadic rationals is not a free Abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

I'm wondering whether $(\mathbb{D}, +)$ the additive group of the dyadic rationals is isomorphic to a free Abelian group or not.

On an intuitive level, it seems like it's obviously nonfree, but I'm wondering how you prove it.

For any given finite set $X \subset \mathbb{D}$, $X$ does not generate $\mathbb{D}$. We can prove this by picking $\frac{1}{2^{1+n}}$ where $2^n$ is the largest denominator in $X$.

We know that $|X| \le \aleph_0$ by a cardinality argument.

This leaves countably infinite $X$.

If $X \subset \frac{1}{2^\mathbb{N}}$ and $X$ generates $\mathbb{D}$, then, since $X$ is not finite, any element of $X$ can be generated by adding together the next smaller element an appropriate number of times.

So far, so good.

The step that I'm struggling with is the other countably infinite cases.

If $X$ is countably infinite and has an upper bound on the size of its denominators, then it can't generate $\mathbb{D}$.

Suppose $X$ is countably infinite and has no upper bound on the size of its denominators.

I'm not sure how to show that any fixed $x \in X$ is a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements taken from $\{ y : y \in X \land y < x \}$.

Comment: Instead of thinking about specific generating sets, I would instead think about why $\mathbb{D}$ cannot be isomorphic to the abstract free abelian group on a countably infinite set.  Find some group-theoretic property that distinguishes these two groups.

Comment: Why not just show directly that if $F$ is the free abelian group on a set $X$, then no generator (= element of $X$) is "divisible by $2$" in $F$?

Comment: The dyadics are $2$-divisible (for evey $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $2y=x$). If it were free on $X$, then the fact that an $x\in X$ can be written as twice something gives a contradiction (express $y$ in terms of the basis).

Comment: The argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3430516/742) solves the problem.